# DRF- multiple search filter with AND condition

Tags: django-rest-framework

I want to implement with multiple search with AND condition. I have implemented like below, but multiple search is working fine with OR condition. But I need to apply AND condition How can i achieve??
views.py

```
class EmployeeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = EmployeeSearchSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        search_query = self.request.query_params.get('search')
        split_query = search_query.split()
        employment = None
        employee1 = []
        employment1 = []
        for query in split_query:
            employee = PositionFulfillment.objects.filter(
                Q(employment__employee__code__icontains=query) |
                Q(employment__employee__person__name__icontains=query) |
                Q(employment__employee__person__surname__icontains=query)
            )
            if employee:
                employee1.append(employee)
            print("employee", employee1)
            active_employee = PositionFulfillment.objects.filter(primary_flag=True, thru_date=None)
            if active_employee:
                employment = active_employee.filter(
                    Q(position__position_type__name__icontains=query) |
                    Q(employment__organization__name__icontains=query) |
                    Q(employment__status__status__employment_status__icontains=query)
                )
            if employment:
                employment1.append(employment)
        all_results = list(chain(*employee1, *employment1))
        return all_results
```

serializers.py

```
class EmployeeSearchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    code = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, source='employment.employee.code')
    name = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, source='employment.employee.person.name')
    surname = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, source='employment.employee.person.surname')
    position = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, source='position.position_type.name')
    organization = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, source='employment.organization.name')
    status = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, source='employment.status.status.employment_status')

    class Meta:
        model = PositionFulfillment
        fields = ["code", "name", "surname", "position", "organization", "status"]
```

Any help appreciated,..

```
Note:I am passing data through postman params search = xxx yyyy
```

Comment: You applied OR condition. Do you wants to apply `OR` condition or `AND` ?

Comment: I want to apply AND condition

Comment: I want to apply AND condition with multple search. I have applied OR condition between fields.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass them as separate arguments to the filter methods, or even chain filtering :

> Keyword argument queries – in filter(), etc. – are “AND”ed together.
> If you need to execute more complex queries (for example, queries with
> OR statements), you can use Q objects.

```
Poll.objects.get(
    Q(question__startswith='Who'),
    Q(pub_date=date(2005, 5, 2)) | Q(pub_date=date(2005, 5, 6))
)
```

Gives :

```
SELECT * from polls WHERE question LIKE 'Who%'
AND (pub_date = '2005-05-02' OR pub_date = '2005-05-06')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Comment: I couldnot specify fields i wanted to search all fieldsWhat i want means, split_query=['front'], It will filter where front is available, when i give split=['front','back'] it will filter both front and back available. How can i achieve???

Comment: You can use https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ if that ease you work. Or build you're query args based on the provided array, but what does it mean filtering front and back, on which field ??? Do you mean that you want to query ALL fields ?

Comment: Yes i want to check all the fields which i have mentioned above codes..